$f:S^n\to S^n$ is continuous, prove that $\Lambda(f)=1+(-1)^n\mathrm{deg}f$

$f:S^n\to S^n$ is continuous, prove that $\Lambda(f)=1+(-1)^n\mathrm{deg}f$.

The definition of the Lefschetz number is: $K$ is a complex, for $f:|K|\to |K|$  a continuous map,
$$\Lambda(f)=\sum_{p=0}^{\mathrm{dim}K}(-1)^p\mathrm{tr}f_{*p}, $$
where  $f_{*p}:H_p(K;\mathbb Q)\to H_p(K;\mathbb Q)$  is the induced homomorphism.
(1) I think that $H_p(S^n;\mathbb Q)=0 $ for $1\le p \le n-1$, but I only know that $H_p(S^n;\mathbb Z)=0\ (1\le p \le n-1)$ . And also I do not know whether $H_n(S^n;\mathbb Q)\simeq \mathbb Q$. (My textbook doesn't give any example of computing $H_p(K;\mathbb Q)$, it just says that universal coefficient theorem can be used.)
(2) I also tried to use that $$\Lambda(f)=\sum_{p=0}^{\mathrm{dim}K}(-1)^p\mathrm{tr}f_{p}, $$where  $f_{p}:C_p(K;\mathbb Q)\to C_p(K;\mathbb Q)$  is the chain map. But this seems very complex.
Could you give some hints or explain the definition of the Lefschetz number and $\mathrm{deg}f$?  Many thanks in advance.

And so did you, as your textbook suggested, try to use the universal coefficient theorem?

Currently I haven't understood the universal coefficient theorem. It's very complex for me. And in the universal coefficient theorem, it seems that I have to compute $\mathrm{Tor}(\cdot ,\mathbb Q)$, and I am struggling understanding what it is saying.

You can use that $\operatorname{Tor}_i(A,B)=0$ when $i>0$ and either $A$ or $B$ is a free abelian group (actually just a flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module is enough).

If you don't want to use the Universal Coefficient Theorem, you can also compute $H_{\ast}(S^n;\mathbb{Q})$ directly. Recall whatever technique you used to compute $H_{\ast}(S^n;\mathbb{Z})$ and I'm positive the calculations goes through almost verbatim if you replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks a lot for these comments! So may I ask whether it's true that by using $\mathrm{Tor}(\cdot,\mathbb Q)=0$, $H_p(S^n;\mathbb Q)\simeq H_p(S^n;\mathbb Z)\otimes \mathbb Q$?

Yes, and perhaps even easier: $\text{Tor}(\mathbb{Z}, -) = 0$ since $\mathbb{Z}$ is free abelian. ($\mathbb{Q}$ is flat but not free.) So $H_p(S^n; \mathbb{Q}) \cong H_p(S^n; \mathbb{Z}) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$.
